# 95 manual civic... loud knocking sound when decelerating

Tags: honda, civic, manual-transmission

I have a 95 civic lx standard ... Recently on way home from work it started making a knocking sound after I let go of the gas . I pulled off fwy put it up on two jacks engaged gears accelerated then decelarated and it was fine no noise. I put it off jacks continued to drive home and nothing changed its still there a knocking loud noise that goes away after I accelerate or hit the brake.

Comment: Check your motor mounts.

Comment: Is it a repetitive rapping knock or a single knock with each gas pedal movement?